# After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, Shortcut Keys don't work

Tags: gnome, upgrade, nautilus, gnome-terminal, 18.04

April 28, 2018 I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and everything worked fine. Now, I don't know why I can't get into Nautilus. When I click the Files icon in the dock it starts to load but nothing launches.

I also can't get into the terminal (neither with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> nor with the terminal icon). I don't know if the two problems are related, but they started to happen at the same time.

**Edit 1:** Rolled up from answer that should be in question, the Nautilus problem was (partially) solved:

> I managed to open nautilus from Konsole and now it seems to work fine
>   (I can open it through the dock). However, when I close the Konsole,
>   it fails again.

Comment: The answer is available here and it works just fine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xVWL-5ery4

Comment: The shortcut I'm asking about is set by default and it already appears in the hotkey list. That is not the answer.

Answer (score 17):

About the "Shortcut Keys don't work" part..
I had a simmilar issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 :
-   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> didn't work
-   lock screen ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> ) didn't work
-   media keys didn't work

Here is what worked for me:

- I installed "compizconfig-settings-manager"
- I opened "General" -> "Commands" and activated the check box on the left "activate commands" and then clicked "Back"

At this point the shortcuts started to work again.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: It is strange because I think that Compiz does not work with Gnome? But I will try

Comment: Yes it works for me. Even, if I have compiz-sm installed shortcuts doesn't work. During installation some configuration files were, probably, overridden and to fix that you need open csm → General → Commands deactivate it and activate one more time. Now it works

Answer (score 3):

My trick to solve it:

1. Install konsole (KDE Terminal) with

   ```
   sudo apt install konsole
   ```
2. In

   > Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard

   click "Terminal" and change the its shortcut (for one you won't be using).
3. Scroll to the bottom and press <kbd>+</kbd> to add a new shortcut. Write `konsole` in Command and choose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> as shortcut (choose whatever name you want).

I had the same problem. It's an annoying bug.

Answer (score 1):

I found the Screen lock shortcut changed to Super+L (<kbd>Windows</kbd> +<kbd>L</kbd>) in 18.04, or at least the default changed for my machine from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

This isn't all bad as I'm used to locking my work machine (Windohs) with Super+L.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04 probably has the keyboard shortcut set to disabled. Furthermore, there is no "Applications" menu option so these steps below work without third-party installations.

- Go to Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard, then scroll to "Navigation Section."
- Click "Hide all normal windows" which is probably set to "disabled."
- Enter your new keyboard shortcut, which I set to CTRL+Alt+D.

Voila! Instant desktop!

Comment: only this worked for me. Ubuntu 18.04, After setting shortcut for launching terminal finally Ctrl+Alt+T opens terminal now, and Ctrl+T opens new tabs in webbrowser and in nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut keys aren't working for:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal. You have to open Dash (tap the Windows/Super Key), type `gnome-terminal` and select it.
- <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to capture screen image. You have to open Dash, type `screenshot` and select it.
- <kbd>Volumne Up</kbd>, <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> and other Media keys aren't working. You'll need to go into Settings, select the appropriate control panel and adjust sliders manually.

This per [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1759462) I read yesterday. Only two people claim to be effected by this bug even though many have commented. I urge you and anyone else effected to register on the bug report. Then subscribe to "bug mail" so you will be updated when the status changes or a fix is in.

---

After upgrading and rebooting your first step should have been to open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

If you did not do this, try it before subscribing to bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Check your hotkeys in `dconf`. I have this problem with `CTRL+SHIFT+E`, It's trying to load emoji language things for me (IBUS related) so I will go ahead and delete that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made a clean install of Lubuntu 18.04 and found myself with the same issue, hotkeys were not working. After reading openbox-lxde support online help I noticed that some required software packages were missing. I recalled having selected a minimal install. The working solution I found in Lubuntu 18.04 was to issue the following commands:

```
sudo apt install openbox-lxde-session
openbox-lxde --reconfigure
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I've just tried the opposite of what @vvervvurm suggested. However, his answer was a good lead -- the compizconfig settings manager is involved.

So, on Ubuntu 18.04, I had all shortcuts properly set under Keyboard/Shortcuts/Sound and Media. And the system just wouldn't pick them up, I could roll the volume up and down all I like; it changed nothing.

When I saw the compizconfig-related answer, I had a look. All shortcuts in there were empty, and enabled. So, I got an idea... what if these all-empty settings were overriding my well-set settings. So, I disabled the shortcuts. PAM. The settings from Ubuntu's Keyboard/Shortcuts just started to work.

So, that was it for me. The compizconfig was overriding the legitimate settings with empty ones. Disabling its keyboard shortcuts made the Ubuntu ones work.