# Ctrl-Alt-T stopped working after installing GNOME Shell on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04

After I installed GNOME Shell, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> combination stopped working.

How could I fix it?

Comment: How and why did you install GNOME shell on Ubuntu 18.04? It comes with GNOME by default.

Comment: If other shortcut keys don't work could be this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1759462 If so this question would become duplicate of this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029730/after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-18-04-shortcut-keys-dont-work?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to **Settings** -> **Devices** -> **Keyboard**, then add  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> if it does not exist.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Upgraded to 18.04 from 16.04 ; kept my preference for the Unity desktop. But couldn't open the terminal with a key combo despite checking the shortcut in the checked answer.

- Install `compizconfig-settings-manager`
- Run `ccsm`
- Turn off the "Commands" plugin

This resolved the lack of <kbd>ctrl-alt-T</kbd>, <kbd>Vol +/-</kbd>, all the other extended and media keys on my keyboard.

Comment: Works like a charm. I started to have problems when starting to use big 4k monitor

Comment: The problem comes back after a reboot. To get it to work, you can either disable or enable or disable/enable in one go. It just needs a click on the checkbox. Not sure why this works but its not the best solution.